# Preparing a database for multi user operation

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a simple question regarding multiuser operation for ORACLE 11g. So i am planning to make an app that should be ready to handle concurrent transaction from > 200 users.

I want to know to organize multi-user configuration in oracle for best performance. Right now I have a user named SEC_USER that saves username and password in a table. so when more than one user logged in, they are under the user SEC_USER.

Is this configuration good enough when the user grows to lets say 400 users? or should i execute 400 times create user from SYSDBA?

Would that be affecting the concurrent transaction as the time grows ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Whether all your connections are for the same user or different ones is completely irrelevant for performance.

Comment: what do you mean by irrelevant ? so u mean that both solutions will have the same performance ?

Comment: That is what Mat means, yes.